# Is there a holomorphic function $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C }$ such that $|f(z)|=\exp(|z|^{2})$ for all $ z\in \mathbb{D}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

\mathbb{D}{} is the unit disc.
We got this question in our complex analysis class and I've got no intuition, whether there is such a function or not.
I tried using the Theorem of Liouville since $\exp(|z|^2)$ is bounded by $1$ and $e$ for $z \in \mathbb{D}$,

Comment: Please define "$\Bbb{D}$" .

Comment: *Hint*: minimum modulus principle.

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations put constraints on the derivatives of $u$ and $v$ for a holomorphic function $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv (x,y)$.  This additional requirement says that $u^2+v^2=\exp(2x^2+2y^2)$.  Can you differentiate this and reach a conclusion?

Comment: @K.defaoite $\mathbb D$ is the unit disk $\{z \in \mathbb C \;|\; |z| < 1\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is seen that $f$ is non-zero on the simply connected domain $\mathbb{D}$. If it was holomorphic, it would have a holomorphic logarithm $\log f$ on $\mathbb{D}$. By the condition,
$$
\Re \log f(z) =\log |f(z)|= \left| z \right|^2  = x^2  + y^2 .
$$
We know that the real part of a holomorphic function is harmonic, however $x^2+y^2$ is not a harmonic function, i.e., $\log f$ and thus $f$ cannot be holomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(z)f(z^*)=\exp(2zz^*)$, then $\log f(z)+\log f(z^*)=2zz^*$; taking $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial z^*}$ of both sides gives $0=2$.